# Nearby Notifications not showing

Tags: android, android-notifications, eddystone, google-nearby

I've configured three types of beacons:

- Eddystone-UID
- Eddystone-UID with TLM
- iBeacon

They are visible in Google Beacons Dashboard, I see these beacons in Beacon Toolkit App in "Registered" tab too.

I've added two nearby notifications:

[image: Test iBeacon Nearby Notifications]

Unfortunately, I did not receive any notification with this web page. I see my beacons in third party beacon scanner.

When I've started Nearby attractions scan manually:

[image: Nearby attractions manual scan]
[image: Nearby attractions manual scan]

it didn't show any beacon related web pages.

However, when I turn on Eddystone-URL beacon I see this beacon's URL in nearby attractions.

Moreover, I see other attachments for this beacons in my custom app which is using Nearby API.

I've tested it on HTC One (Android 5.0.1) and Nexus 6 (latest Marshmallow).

**So the questions is - how to run and debug Google Nearby Notifications?** How can I show proof-of-concept to my clients?

UPDATE

Logs (Eddystone-URL)

```
07-30 10:00:41.192 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: DiscoveryService scanForScreenOnAndPermissionChange()
07-30 10:00:41.194 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
07-30 10:00:41.194 17608-1520/? D/ChimeraResource: Successfully parsed resource with package name: com.google.android.gms and resource name drawable/quantum_ic_nearby_white_24
07-30 10:00:41.271 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:41.365 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:41.466 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:41.568 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:41.669 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:41.770 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:41.875 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:41.976 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:42.087 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:42.185 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:42.288 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:42.388 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:42.488 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:42.593 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:42.692 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:42.697 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
07-30 10:00:42.699 17608-1520/? D/ChimeraResource: Successfully parsed resource with package name: com.google.android.gms and resource name drawable/quantum_ic_nearby_white_24
07-30 10:00:43.018 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.121 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.224 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.326 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.427 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.528 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.629 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.734 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.836 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:43.935 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:44.038 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:44.241 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
07-30 10:00:44.241 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:44.242 17608-1520/? D/ChimeraResource: Successfully parsed resource with package name: com.google.android.gms and resource name drawable/quantum_ic_nearby_white_24
07-30 10:00:44.342 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:44.447 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:44.755 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:44.861 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.012 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.114 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.163 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.315 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.416 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.520 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.621 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.725 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.768 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
07-30 10:00:45.770 17608-1520/? D/ChimeraResource: Successfully parsed resource with package name: com.google.android.gms and resource name drawable/quantum_ic_nearby_white_24
07-30 10:00:45.828 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:45.929 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:46.137 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:46.241 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:46.547 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:46.646 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:46.749 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:46.855 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:46.955 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:47.056 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:47.161 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:47.259 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:00:47.277 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
07-30 10:00:47.278 17608-1520/? D/ChimeraResource: Successfully parsed resource with package name: com.google.android.gms and resource name drawable/quantum_ic_nearby_white_24
```

Logs iBeacon:

```
07-30 10:02:13.632 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: DiscoveryService scanForScreenOnAndPermissionChange()
07-30 10:02:13.639 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
07-30 10:02:13.709 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:13.811 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:13.912 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.013 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.117 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.217 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.318 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.421 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.521 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.725 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.881 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:14.929 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:15.032 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:15.175 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
07-30 10:02:15.185 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:15.491 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:15.594 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:15.695 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:15.798 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:15.901 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.001 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.101 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.205 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.415 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.511 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.611 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.713 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.815 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.917 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:17.225 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:17.427 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:17.540 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:17.679 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:17.781 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:17.884 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:17.984 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:18.085 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:18.188 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:18.256 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
07-30 10:02:18.291 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:18.390 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:18.492 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:18.599 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:18.908 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:19.011 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:19.111 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:19.213 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:19.318 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:19.419 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:19.520 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:19.798 17608-1520/? D/NearbyDiscovery: Filtered 0 items out
```

In both cases I see this warning:

```
07-30 10:02:16.101 17608-11716/? W/NearbyDiscovery: Runnable[NearbyDirectManager.onStatusUpdate] not posted since looper is exiting
07-30 10:02:16.204 17608-11716/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (almi) {e19752f} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (almi) {e19752f} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                                                     at alme.c(:com.google.android.gms:2255)
                                                     at almc.b(:com.google.android.gms:90)
                                                     at ril.a(:com.google.android.gms:1068)
                                                     at alqj.a(:com.google.android.gms:148)
                                                     at alvp.a(:com.google.android.gms:376)
                                                     at altw.a(:com.google.android.gms:2077)
                                                     at almw.a(:com.google.android.gms:1236)
                                                     at alol.run(:com.google.android.gms:1309)
                                                     at almi.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:241)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Maybe obvious, but if you go to Settings -> Google -> Nearby, is it set to on?

Comment: @davidgyoung yes it is set to on

Answer (score 1):

(I work on Nearby)
You're able to get Eddystone-URL fine but not url thru Discoverer's attachment.  So the suspicion is that it got filtered out somehow. Reasons I see it can get filtered out are

- Empty title or description
- not https (does not apply to your
  case)
- content is inappropriate/invalid so it got filtered out.

To turn on debugging, you can use this command

- "adb shell setprop log.tag.NearbyDiscovery VERBOSE"

Send us the info when you reproduce it and I'll help debug further.

What's the exact content you're trying to attach?

Comment: I've added logs to my question.

Content:
https://droidlabs.net

It works like a charm with Eddystone-URL but no result with Eddystone-UID and iBeacon :(

Comment: Thanks for the attaching those logs.  They're a known issue and we have fixed it and should be coming in the next release.

We'll try to attach to droidlabs.net in house and let you know.

Please also turn on this add'l log and let us know.
"adb shell setprop log.tag.NearbyDirect VERBOSE"

Comment: Looks like you've attached the url with language of "pl"  Can you please reattach with language of "en" to see?

There's a known issue with language.  I'll understand the issue in details come Monday when I'm back to work.

Comment: I've removed nearby notification with "pl" language and when I've added it again but with "en" it started to work! Can you tell more about this known issue with language?

Comment: We have a bug--the client and server didn't agree on the language code convention. Sorry for the trouble this caused. Looks like we'll be able to address it with a server push.

Comment: Just following up, we pushed the server fix in August, the language "pl" should be working in the list view (Settings > Google > Nearby). The notification will be working when the next version of Google Play Services rolls out. The version rolling out now (unfortunately) has a bug that disables the notifications.